# Telegram Bot | Как сделать чтобы бот отвечал на сообщения пользователя который вызвал команду?

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, users

Описание проблемы:

- Мой бот находится в группе где есть несколько участников, и у него есть команда /start с помощью которой он создает базу данных и тд. И если пользователь вызвал команду где бот ждет ответ, и его перебьют то он получит неправильную информацию или выдаст ошибку.

Ситуация:

- Пользователь А вызывает команду /start.
- Бот выдает сообщения после которого ждет ответ от Пользователя А.
- Пользователь А не успевает написать ответ.
- Пользователь Б перебивает(написал сообщение раньше) Пользователя А.
- Из-за чего бот берет и ставит в базу данных информацию Пользователя Б вместо Пользователя который вызвал команду.
- так получается что база данных не соответствует правильным данным, или же выдает ошибку.

**Так вот, хотел спросить, если есть какое либо решение для того чтобы бот мог ждать ответ пользователя который вызвал команду несмотря на того если в группе будут переписываться другие пользователи.**

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('profile_info.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nick varchar(50), tag varchar(50), lang varchar(10))')
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=?', (message.from_user.id,))
    user_data = cur.fetchone()

    if user_data:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы уже зарегистрированы.')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи свое имя.')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_nick)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()


def user_nick(message):
    global nick
    nick = message.text.strip()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи свой тэг:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_tag)


def user_tag(message):
    global tag
    tag = message.text.strip()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи свой язык бота:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_lang)


def user_lang(message):
    lang = message.text.strip()

    conn = sqlite3.connect('profile_info.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "INSERT INTO users (user_id, nick, tag, lang) VALUES ('%s','%s', '%s', '%s')" % (message.from_user.id, nick, tag, lang))
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'готово')
```

Comment: Я не знаю как у вас там на питоне (а судя по коду, это он), но обычно такое делается так называемой "машиной состояния", он-же "конечный автомат", то есть реализуются некие "состояния", которые имеют свои действия, свое меню, свой текст, и т.д. Имея такой подход, логика становится очень простой: `/start` -> записали в базу id пользователя и уникальный идентификатор состояния -> пользователь нажал кнопку -> задали соответствующее состояние, обновили его в базе для указанного пользователя. То есть вы будете знать на каком этапе сейчас пользователь, что позволяет вам продолжить диалог.

Comment: Это как вот в реальной жизни, вам позвонил по телефону "Вася", сказал что-то, вы это у себя в голове запомнили, временно сохранили. Далее к вам с комнату заходит условный "Петя" и предлагает пойти смотреть ТВ, вы это "сохранили" у себя в голове. Вдруг к вам приходит в гости "Вася" и говорит "Так вот, то о чем мы говорили ...", вы "достаете" из головы информацию, и продолжаете ранее начавшийся диалог. Также и тут, состояния и идентификация конкретного человека. Что касается хранения, то это по сути "Кэш" информация, ее стоит хранить временно, условно час. Отлично подходит для этого Redist.

Comment: Вам нужны [Конечные автоматы (FSM)](https://mastergroosha.github.io/aiogram-3-guide/fsm/)